# pandoc LaTex change ` backtick highlight

Tags: latex, pdf-generation, markdown, pandoc

I am using pandoc along with LaTex to create pdf output.

I am highlighting some code using ` backticks.

The text within the backtick is just highlighted using a different font.

How can I change the color of the highlighted text along with the background color.

Note that this is for in-line highlighting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a new file header.tex with this ([from a tex.SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141128/56508)):

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb,newverbs,xcolor}

\definecolor{Light}{gray}{.90}

\let\oldtexttt\texttt
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{
  \colorbox{Light}{\oldtexttt{#1}}
}
```

And then compile your file with `pandoc myfile.md -o myfile.pdf -H header.tex`.

Comment: The command installed a few packages but now getting the following error ...1.16 This is the sentence with code \texttt{the\ issue}...

Comment: Sorry, this was linked to https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1694 : spaces are escaped by pandoc in inline verbatim, which `\hl` didn't like. It worked fine with single word, and I did not test it further. I corrected the code using another answer from tex.SE

Comment: yup it works now..Thanks a lot man..on a sidenote 
 
I want to create pdf file which has syntax hilighting and code blocks..using pandoc is not the best option so far for me as there is a lot of configutation that is taking focus out of my content..Is there a simpler tool that I can use to create pdf with code that has syntax hilighting

Comment: I don't know anything simpler than pandoc for that... [Fenced code blocks](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#fenced-code-blocks) work out of the box (`~~~~ {.python}`) and the configuration is a one line command that you can leave in a makefile.

Comment: can I change the text color of inline code block..Also where can I learn more about the code that you gave me and what is it called?

Comment: This is just latex code. Change the color definition in `\definecolor` (you can google "definecolor latex" to find help)